# which packages do i install from sdk manager in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

i was installing android studio
and when i went to sdk manager it told me to install 10 packages by default .. while these packages were installing  i lost my internet connection so i cancelled the whole process. now when i opened the android studio again on the home screen it says rendering fail and the phone which shows up in the middle of the screen (design view ) doesn't show up. i guess this happened due to some packages where not installed .. so i want to know what the the basic packages that i need to install. could someone post a list or  a screen shot of your installed packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

1. Android SDK tools
2. Android SDK platform-tools
3. Android SDK build-tools
4. Install everything in Android 5.0.1 (API 21) - or whatever the version you want
5. From Extras: Android Support Repository, Android Support Library, Google Play Services, Google Repository, Android Auto API Simulators, Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer)

FYI, I'm using Eclipse IDE, so the names can be different. But these will be there in Android Studio too

Answer (score 1):

Recommended packages by android developers

Android SDK Build Tools - Includes tools to build Android apps.

Android SDK Platform-tools - Includes various tools required by the Android platform, including the adb tool.

Android SDK Tools - Includes essential tools such as the Android Emulator and ProGuard.

Android Support Repository - Includes local Maven repository for Support libraries, which provide an extended set of APIs that are compatible with most versions of Android. It's required for products such as Android Wear, Android TV, and Google Cast.

Google Repository - Includes local Maven repository for Google libraries, which provide a variety of features and services for your apps, such as Google sign-in, Google Maps, Games achievements and leader boards, and much more.

In the SDK Platforms tab, you must also install at least one version of the Android platform. Required. At least one platform is required in your environment so you're able to compile your application. In order to provide the best user experience on the latest devices, use the latest platform version as your build target.